# how to fix this, JavaScript Error : document.forms. is null not an Object

Tags: javascript

in my jsp page, I am getting script error.  **error message is : document.forms[0] is null not an object.**when i click  to SignOut . sign Out works fine and it is redirect to default.jsp. but my default.jsp doesn't show anything just a blank page. I checked view Source of  default.jsp page.The whole page is not loaded. it has loaded only till **1st line of body tag.** Below is the code for **default.jsp .**

```
 <! doctype html>
 <html language="en">
 <%@  page language="java" contentType="text/html" %>
<%@ session ="false" %>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function closeWarning(){

        document.forms[0].reset();

 }
     </script>
</head>

 <body onLoad="closeWarning();" class="page-design">// page loaded till here
 <jsp:include flush="true" page="/myCart/header.jsp"/>
//---other component of body----
 </body>
```

please suggest something how to resolve this. Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must never unconditionally assume that things (like collection members, as `forms[0]`) are there. Doing this in your code is bad style because it triggers run-time errors.

Either you test their existence before you call methods on them:

```
if (document.forms[0]) {
  document.forms[0].reset();
}
// ...and two more
```

or you use a less error prone way to reset every existing form - in this case, a loop.

```
for (var i=0; i<document.forms.length; i++) {
  document.forms[i].reset();
}
```

I'd recommend the latter.

Comment: thanks Tomalak i have used your recommendation now i am not getting any error , but still nothing is displayed on the page. still the page is loaded till 1st line of <body> tag.

Comment: @Kmme83 Are you sure your JSP outputs sensible HTML? Have you checked?

Comment: Jsp outputs correct html, but not everytime. that is out of 5 times 1 time it doesn't show any thing

Answer (score 0):

use `var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');` instead of `document.forms` and then iterate over them to reset them. I'm pretty sure you might have less than 3 forms in your page (in that case, not even one).

Comment: @ greut, thanks for response. do you mean that i should use it like <script>var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('myForm');   </script>       <body><form name="myForm"></form> </body> . how to iterate this please give me reference to any link.